# Looping through NSArray while subtracting values from each object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have NSNumber objects stored in an NSMutableArray.  I am attempting to perform a calculation on each object in the array.

What I want to do is:

1) Take a random higher number variable and keep subtracting a smaller number variable in increments until the value of the variable is equal to the value in the array.

For example:

NSMutableArray object is equal to 2.50.

I have an outside variable of 25 that is not in the array.

I want to subtract 0.25 multiple times from the variable until I reach less than or equal to 2.50.  I also need a parameter so if the number does not divide evenly and goes below the array value, it resorts to the original array value of 2.50.

Lastly, for each iteration, I want to print the values as they are counting down as a string.

I was going to provide code, but I don't want to make this more confusing than it has to be.

So my output would be:

```
VALUE IS: 24.75
VALUE IS: 24.50
VALUE IS: 24.25

…

VALUE IS: 2.50

END
```

Comment: Better you provide code so that will get to know where is the issue??

Comment: As Hussain mentions, stack overflow isn't a sub-contracting site.  Please at least attempt a solution and get back if you have issues.

Comment: I have code… but I was looking for a generic answer so as not to complicate things… I was hoping for something with Fast Enumeration...

Comment: So where is you fast enumeration try?

Comment: I don't see why you had to -1 my question man… I know how to perform a loop but this is something different because it involves an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on my iPad so this won't be as nice as I would like

```
float randomValue = 25; //or however you get the value
float subtractionValue = 0.25 // or whatever value or use a define
for (NSNumber *n in myArray)
{
  while (randomValue > n.floatvalue)
  {
    randomValue -= subtractionValue;
    NSLog(@"Value is: %f", randomValue);
    if (randomValue < 2.5)
    {
      randomValue = n.floatvalue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo - the variable `n` should be a pointer.

Comment: You can't use > to compare a float to an NSNumber

Comment: How’s that, Catfish? Thanks.

Comment: NSNumber is a pointer type. > on pointers compares their address, not their value.

Answer (score 0):

Well run the while loop and check like that below:-
 Lets assume your variable here whose value is 25

```
         float a=25;
    while (a>=2.50)
    {
     a=a-0.25;
     NSlog(@"count is %f",a);
    }
```

Hope it helps, it is just the logic you can try with your code and if required please modify accordingly.

Comment: Where does the array come into this?  Also that `a != 2.50` check is dodgy...

Comment: @trojanfoe correct, but the op has not mention any code here so just giving the idea how to implement. Also condition have modified.

Comment: Please let me know if the above code is useless. Then i will delete the same as i have not tested;)